# Data validation in Silverlight 4 - Entity level validation vs ViewModel validation

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm working with Silverlight 4, MVVM, WCF RIA and Entity Framework. As I know, there are two ways to do data validation. First is [entity level validation](http://team.silverlight.net/tips-and-training/silverlight-tv-52-entity-level-validation-defining-metadata-and-nested-comboboxes-with-wcf-ria-services/), second is write down [validation logic in ViewModel](http://thejoyofcode.com/Silverlight_Validation_and_ViewModel.aspx).

Currently I create validation logic inside ViewModel, so I want to know pros and cons of each way.

Comment: I don't want to watch the whole video so can I ask is entity level validation the same as data annotations validation attributes on your entites in your middle tier which are generated client side when you're using RIA?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, entity level validation is attribute validation on entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataAnnotation` attributes can be applied to `ViewModel` too. But problems are the same:

- Throwing of exceptions on validation errors - noise in the output window
- Setting some default value to a property, it throws exceptions and set an invalid state
- Impossible to validate a model completely and receive all its errors.
- Impossible to add or clear errors in code.

The advantage is simplicity of data annotations in comparison with other ways.

On the other hand, the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface allows to perform validation asynchronously. As it was mentioned in other answer, if you want to check whether a username is already exist in the database, you can send a request to the service and add an error to the UI after receiveing an asyncronous callback.

I prefer to use `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and although it requires more code than data annotations, it can be reduced by creating a sort of generic validator class:

```
this.Validator = new ModelValidator<ProfileViewModel>(this);
this.Validator.AddValidationFor(() => this.SelectedCountry).NotNull().Show("Select country");
this.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(this.ValidateChangedProperty);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a cop out but you'll probably end up needing to do both types of validation.

Entity level validation is useful as you only have to define it in one place and you get UI validation messages and entity validation before it gets saved to the database (assuming that data is being saved to a db).

The trouble is that entity level validation is fairly basic and you'll probably need to make some service calls to do custom validation (for example, we validate that a user exists on our network for a provided username in our create user form). This is where you need to do validation in your VM.

Comment: If you use entity-level validation, how can you notify validation error to textbox binding to that entity?

Comment: The setter on the generated property throws an exception when it's set to an invalid value, silverlight catches these exceptions and sets the control to the correct visual state. I don't know the exact details but it "just works"

Comment: How you set its binding? I try to set binding of TextBox's Text property to Text="{Binding MyEntity.MyProperty, ... }" but it isn't work.

Comment: There could be a million problems with a binding. You might need this property set on the binding to show validation errors "NotifyOnValidationError=true". Try "{Binding Path=MyEntity.MyProperty...)". Try adding a TextBlock with a binding {Binding} and it will enable you to check you're bound to the type yo think you are.